# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process error while opening a maximised window with start

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have recently made code to open a excel spreadsheet that contains my homework information. The spreadsheet is contained within a folder named "Homework" completely by itself. The unfortunate thing is I got to a point where I wanted the spreadsheet to open maximised. I added a piece of code that should make it work, and it did, but it fed the command prompt with this error

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Here is all the code I am currently using:

```
@echo off
SET "stime=10:00:00.00"
SET "etime=16:00:00.00"
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.EXE" 2>NUL | find /I /N "EXCEL.EXE">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
set "running=true"
) else (
set "running=false"
)
:start
IF %time% GEQ %stime% (
    IF %time% LEQ %etime% (
        IF %running%==false (
            for %%i in (G:\Homework\*) do %%i
            GOTO start
        ) Else (
            GOTO start
            )
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO start
        )
) ELSE (
    GOTO start
    )
```

Comment: Won't `:start` `IF %time% GEQ %stime% (` `IF %time% LEQ %etime% (` `IF %running%==false (` `for %%i in (G:\Homework\*) do %%i` `GOTO start` try to go into an infinite loop opening your files, and crash on the second time through (when the files are already open and in use)?

Comment: YowE3K, you make a good point, a point that actually fixed this. I had forgotten to continuously be checking if the file is running, and so it will screw up as soon as it tries to complete that loop. Thanks.

Comment: Glad something I said helped - I know nothing about "batch-file", so was only looking at the question because of the "excel" tag.

Comment: You still have a logic problem. You are only checking to see if a program is running. You are not checking to see if that program has a file open.

Comment: Squashman, could you perhaps suggest a way of checking for that information, I am fairly knew to playing around with Batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
@echo off
SET "stime=10:00:00.00"
SET "etime=16:00:00.00"
:start
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.EXE" 2>NUL | find /I /N "EXCEL.EXE">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
   set "running=true"
) else (
   set "running=false"
)
IF %time% GEQ %stime% IF %time% LEQ %etime% IF %running%==false (
   for %%i in (G:\Homework\*) do start /MAX %%i
)
GOTO start
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out where I had screwed up. The process hadn't been checking to see if the ile was already open. A few quick changes and I had made it so the process correctly checks and opens the file when necessary.

New code:

```
@echo off
SET "stime=10:00:00.00"
SET "etime=16:00:00.00"
:start
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq EXCEL.EXE" 2>NUL | find /I /N "EXCEL.EXE">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
set "running=true"
) else (
set "running=false"
)
IF %time% GEQ %stime% (
    IF %time% LEQ %etime% (
        IF %running%==false (
            for %%i in (G:\Homework\*) do start /MAX %%i
            GOTO start
        ) Else (
            GOTO start
            )
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO start
        )
) ELSE (
    GOTO start
    )
```

Although this works it isn't ideal and I would like to know if there are any better ways of making this code work.